# Program to change the phone numbers a call is redirected to if a mobile phone cannot be reached?

Tags: java, iphone, nokia, motorola

Is it possible to write a program that will change the phone numbers a mobile phone redirects calls to if it cannot be reached by the network?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand:  You want your phone, during the period that it can't communicate with the network, to tell the network to forward its calls to another number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the following link describes how to do it on Symbian at least:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_set_call_forwarding_state

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible.

If you're talking about general PTSN and mobile networks, you'll probably need to do so as a service on the network operators IN (intelligent networking) platform(s). Obviously this would be a service provided by the network operation, so I suspect though that's not quite what you're asking about.

If you're talking about a mobile phone redirecting calls that cannot be made to a number the caller (rather than the person called) decides, then you'll need to craft a solution specific to the phone OS.

I'm not familiar enough to know how to do this on a per phone system platform I'm afraid, though I know for the iPhone you'll need to use something other than Java.

Answer (score -1):

Neither the functionality you're describing ("intercepting" a call), nor an implementation in Java, would be possible on the iPhone (at least currently, using the official SDK).

Comment: It is not really "intercepting" a call, although it might be called that in IPhone terms. I can change the configuration I am talking about on all Nokia mobiles I have owned recently. There it is called call redirecting, I believe.

Comment: Redirecting, intercepting, whatever you call it, when the user dials out (using the built-in interface), you can't hook into the "result" of the call, on the iPhone. It's all done outside the scope of the apps you can write.